# OpenCart admin menu link url

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, opencart

I'm verry new to OpenCart and I'm trying to make a module for it.

I want a link in the admin menu to the module I am creating thus I've edited this file:

```
/admin/view/template/common/header.tpl
```

The code I have added:

```
<li><a class="top">Import / Export</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="" target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

My question is propably verry simple:

In the normal links the url for the `<a href="">` is set like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $report_customer_online; ?>">
```

**How can i make an url to the right module with the token of OpenCart?**

The module path is `module/order_export`.

If you need more info, feel free to ask...

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are planning to do this for sale you should use vQmod ([link](http://vqmod.com/)) for it rather than requiring people to edit files. Almost all carts have vQmod already installed on them

Comment: @JayGilford, thanks for the point out. Almost forgot about that. But now i know how it works, so using VQMod will not be that hard... Thank you anyway ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16418443/598500 - I have answered for the very similar question, anyway the answer is the same as for Your question.

But to guide You more precisely:

**language file `/admin/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/common/header.php`** add e.g.:

```
$_['text_my_module'] = 'My Module Title';
```

**controller file `/admin/controller/common/header.php`** add e.g.:

```
$this->data['text_my_module'] = $this->language->get('text_my_module');
```

and

```
$this->data['my_module'] = $this->url->link('module/order_export', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

and finally **the template file `/admin/view/template/common/header.tpl`** add:

```
<a href="<?php echo $my_module; ?>" class="top"><?php echo $text_my_module; ?></a>
```

where applicable...

Is this the correct answer for You?

Comment: THank you so verry much for your clear guide. Have been strugeling with this for a couple of days... Thank you verry verry much

Comment: And You are so very welcome! Next time come here to ask earlier (like after couple of **hours**, not days) ;-)

Comment: A good read too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10700761/how-to-create-a-custom-admin-page-in-opencart

Comment: @shadyyx Thanks a lot whenever I search here mostly I found your answer very perfect and precise. Learning a lot from you. :)

Comment: @techansaari You are welcome. I am here just for that purpose ;-)

Comment: in opencart 2.3.0.2 you need to make  '$this->data' to '$data'.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to create. but you need to edit the following files and add some link works like what they said above. But it will be vanished. when you go with Opencart update. So here is a VQMod Link creation example and its extension. Try this/

http://kvcodes.com/2014/06/how-to-create-admin-menu-link-for-custom-admin-page-opencart/

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. While your answer remains here, the link might change or become otherwise unavailable. Please edit your answer to contain the essentials of the link, so it will remain helpful regardless of the link's state.

Answer (score 1):

> In Opencart 2:

**language file** `/admin/language/<YOUR_LANGUAGE>/common/menu.php` add e.g.:

```
$_['text_my_module'] = 'My Module Title';
```

**controller file** `/admin/controller/common/menu.php` add e.g.:

```
$data['text_my_module'] = $this->language->get('text_my_module');
```

and

```
$data['my_module'] = $this->url->link('catalog/my_module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

and finally the **template file** `/admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl` add:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $my_module; ?>">text_my_module</a></li>
```

where applicable...

Comment: Thank you very much, This helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anuj!

I did it with OpenCart 2.3 and the files to edit are column-left instead of menu.

And if you want your link to look like the other main categories here is the code with the class :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $my_module; ?>"><i class="fa fa-clock-o fw"></i><span><?php echo $text_my_module ?></span></a></li>
```

Note that I also included an icon from Font Awesome into the class of < i >